# How I can set value before using RemoveAt(i) on Angular Reactive Form Array?

Tags: angular

How I can set value before using RemoveAt(i) on Angular Reactive Form Array?

```
  removeCustomerPhone(custIndex: number, phoneIndex: number) {
    // this.customerPhones(custIndex).at(phoneIndex).setValue({
    //   'IsDeleted': true
    // })
     this.customerPhones(custIndex).removeAt(phoneIndex, {
      emitEvent  : false
    });
  }
```

Following is the methods to bind phones:-

`````
customerPhones(custIndex: number): FormArray {
    return this.Addresses()
      .at(custIndex)
      .get('Phones') as FormArray;
  }
 
  newPhone(): FormGroup {
    this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ID:0,
      phone1: '',
      addressId:0,
      IsDeleted:false
    });
    this.phoneForm.valueChanges.subscribe(a=>{
      a.stateEnum = State.Modified
    });
    return this.phoneForm;
  }
````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to give value to a FormGroup you use [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue) but you need give one value to each field of the formGroup: `

```
   this.customerPhones(custIndex).at(phoneIndex)
        .setValue({ID:..,phone1:...,addressId:...,IsDeleted:...})
```

If you only want to change one property (o severals but not all) you use [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue)

```
this.customerPhones(custIndex).at(phoneIndex)
            .patchValue({IsDeleted:true})
```